# Why Would An Adventurer Use A Literal Sword Frog?

Tags: weapons, mythical-creatures

After seeing this question [Why would an adventurer use a sword frog?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/174385/why-would-an-adventurer-use-a-sword-frog?rq=1) I must admit I was a bit disappointed, though I understand it was a legitimate question. Understandably enough, I thought the question was about an adenturer using a frog with a sword-like tongue as a weapon.

So, now I'm making my own version of the question: **Why Would An Adventurer Use A Literal Sword Frog?**

Someone said this question was highly dependent on in-world information; I disagree on the grounds that most people can figure out the typical adventurer: adventurous (of course), noble and heroic or seeking fame and profit. The typical adventurer would (most likely) consider wielding a sword frog just because it's cool, but I'm not sure the benefits of the Sword Frog (information below) outweigh the drawbacks of having to not only tame and feed your weapon, but has a will of its own and *won't* cooperate with you all the time.

Specifications:

1. Sword frogs range in size from the Little Grass Frog (which has a needle-sized tongue) to a goliath bullfrog (which has a broadsword-sized tongue). Regular Sword Frogs have tongues like knives.
2. Sword frog's tongues can turn from rigid as steel to as flexible as you'd expect a frog tongue to be, allowing them to strike prey with their tongues and then harden the tongue so the prey can't claw or bite  it off, or perhaps wind their tongue around a branch and harden it to prevent predators from cutting them down.
   They can also elongate (extend) and shorten (retract) their tongues, and vary the width and length of their tongue; as an example, LGFs can have a *really* short, wide point for a tongue or a long, thin needle-like tongue or something in between. By extension, sword frogs can also control the sharpness of their tongues, turning them from blades to bludgeons.
3. Sword Frogs can understand human speech and expressions, are always hungry, usually grumpy and somewhat temperamental (DO NOT try to steal a sword frog), and can be trained to extend and retract their tongues on the press of a "button" on the frog's back. However, Sword Frogs rarely allow people to catch and wield them, instead running from or attacking them.

As always, I appreciate your input and feedback, thank you for sharing! If you see a problem, please let me know so I can fix it, and if more information is needed, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: This question is opinion based or is highly dependent on in world information.

Comment: Why? Three words: Psychedelic Toad Venom (frogs, too!)

Comment: I don't understand --- how would one wield a [sword frog](https://irongatearmory.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ULF-LP-16-Frog-with-Brass-Buckles.jpg)? Or do you really mean a [frog sword](https://www.etsy.com/listing/928087679/mariposa-frog-handle-cheese-knife-1999?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=knife+frog&ref=sr_gallery-1-2)? There's a world of difference! I disagree that the query is dependent on in-world information so much as good understanding of English nominal compounding conventions!

Answer (score 5):

## Self fixing blade

If you ever spar with metal blades, you will notice that your blade requires maintenance. Depending on what you're handling and your style you'll get scratched, bent or chipped blades. The handle might also become loose or disconnect from the blade altogether depending on the abuse. And then there is rust if you don't oil ot every now and then, specially if the scabbard is not a good one.

With a living being I'd expect metabolism to deal with most of these factors, as long as you give your frog time to heal.

## Rule of Cool

The mangá and animé for Naruto features characters who foght with their tongues, because mangá and animé. One of these characters is a sensient frog (named Fukasaku, if you wish to Google for him), who can harden his tongue just as you say. Of course, this being a shonen story, this kermit-sized creature can extend his hardened tongue a few hundred feet and slash enemies and the ground with a single slash.

## Trolling PETA for the lulz

Frankly, if I were to write a compendium on fictional weapons, the sword frog would go in the same chapters and tables as the [gopher-chucks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBrU7XiGzdc).